# Processing 2.2.1 not recognising OpenCV library folder

Tags: opencv, processing, libraries

I have downloaded the OpenCV library folder from: https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing and put the folder into the processing libraries folder with all my other libraries. When I go to the examples folder in OpenCV and run one, it says it says that there is no OpenCV library installed.

Comment: What exactly is your directory structure? What is inside the OpenCV library folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the download link from github there's a chance the unzipped folder might be *opencv_processing-master* instead of *opencv_processing*.

You can try to rename the opencv_processing-master folder to opencv_processing and restart Processing.

For the simplest/safest way to install the library I recommend using the Library Manager:

1. cleanup/remove the unzipped folder you have if it's in Documents/Processing
2. Go to **Processing > Sketch > Import Library ... > Add Library ... > type OpenCV > select OpenCV for Processing > click Install**

It might even work without having to restart Processing